# Why are my Ship's SFX a lot quieter?

Tags: rebel-galaxy

When I started playing *Rebel Galaxy* I could clearly hear my Engines, Warp Drive and Broad Side Canons. However now they seem very silent and even after setting the Music Setting to ~25 and SFX to 100 the music still is louder than them.

The interface noises are fine like normal like when I change speeds or when when you hear dialog either from conversations or the Ship's notifications (ie. "Engines at Max" or "Stellar Map").

I have:

- Checked by PC's speaker settings and they are set at Stereo in case Windows went to set it to 5.1 Surround Sound for some reason
- Checked for Realtek Driver updates (there are none)
- Checked other games of which they  are fine
- Deleted and restored the version I have backed up which is a fresh non-played download

I get the feeling the quieter sounds are not meant to be like this since they were louder when I started. So have I missed something in fixing this sound issue?